# Setting radio button value property to true to show its selected in user-form

Tags: vba, excel, vb6

I have 3 radio buttons on user-form. I have to set the default status of radio button (checked) when form loads, based on the value in the Range("R" & rNo)

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

If Worksheets("static").Range("R" & 
Activation.getMachineIDIndexNo) = 1 Then
radio1yr.value = True

ElseIf Worksheets("static").Range("R" & 
Activation.getMachineIDIndexNo) = 6 Then
radio6mon.value = True

ElseIf Worksheets("static").Range("R" & 
Activation.getMachineIDIndexNo) = 3 Then
radio3mon.value = True
End If
```

And I also have codes on radio-button click event

```
 Private Sub radio1yr_Click()
'// some code
 End Sub

Private Sub radio3mon_Click()
'// some code
End Sub

Private Sub radio6mon_Click()
'// some code
End Sub
```

with this code:

> radio3mon.value = True

The problem I'm facing is when the form loads it also executes the code in  **radio-button click event** which I do not want.

I want radiobutton click event to run only when the user wishes to select one of the buttons after the form loads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a global boolean variable to store if the form has been initialised or not:

```
Dim IsEnabled as Boolean
```

Then in the `Initialize()` method set the `IsEnabled` as `False` at the start, then true once the form has been initialised:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   IsEnabled = False
   If Worksheets("static").Range("R" & Activation.getMachineIDIndexNo) = 1 Then
      radio1yr.value = True

   ElseIf Worksheets("static").Range("R" & Activation.getMachineIDIndexNo) = 6 Then
      radio6mon.value = True

   ElseIf Worksheets("static").Range("R" & Activation.getMachineIDIndexNo) = 3 Then
      radio3mon.value = True
   End If
   IsEnabled = True
End Sub
```

In the click events, exit the subroutine if `IsEnabled` is `False`.

```
Private Sub radio1yr_Click()
   If Not IsEnabled Then
      Exit Sub
   End If
   '// some code
 End Sub

Private Sub radio3mon_Click()
If Not IsEnabled Then
   Exit Sub
End If
'// some code
End Sub

Private Sub radio6mon_Click()
   If Not IsEnabled Then
      Exit Sub
   End If
   '// some code
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much great solution

Comment: We tend to name this variable something like "isUserInput" to distinguish the case where it is automatic. Initially this would default to False, and later only once the form is entirely loaded it is set to True. This also comes in handy in other cases where you wish to suppress form events from cascading; ie you can set its value at other times.

Answer (score 1):

Dim a module-wide Boolean variable, "Loaded", and set it to True at the end of the Initialize procedure.

Then at the start of each Click() procedure, insert:

```
If Not Loaded Then Exit Sub
```